# Conditional Probability giving me wrong answer

Tags: probability

Exercise 2.
There are only three ferry companies that operate from the Greek island of Symi: F1, F2 and F3. F1 has
6 sailings per day, of which 20% are delayed. F2 has 9 sailings per day, of which 25% are delayed. F3
has 5 sailings per day, of which 10% are delayed. You randomly hear someone at the port of Symi
complaining about their delayed ferry trip. What is the probability that they are traveling on ferry
company F1?

I am trying to do this question and have arrived at the following answer with this working:
$(.6*.2)+(.9*.25)+(.5*.1) = 0.395$ I am then dividing this value by $0.6$ from the original question and giving me a answer of $0.6583$. I feel this answer is wrong but I'm not sure why - I think it may have something to do with the first calculation I do of the total probability? Any help appreciated here. Many thanks.

Comment: Why $0.6,0.8,0.5$ when each company provides $6:9:5$ respectively of the $20$ ferry trips made in a day?

Comment: So I should be using 0.3, 0.45 and 0.25 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an argument less obviously dependent on conditional probabilities:

Per day, you have an expected value of $(6\times 0.2) + (9\times 0.25) + (5\times 0.1)$ $= 1.2+2.25+0.5$ $= 3.95$ late ferries.

The expected proportion of those belonging to company $F1$ is $\dfrac {1.2}{3.95} \approx 0.3038$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
P(F1|C) &= \frac{P(C|F1)\cdot P(F1)}{P(C)} \\
&= \frac{P(C|F1)\cdot P(F1)}{P(C|F1)\cdot P(F1) + P(C|F2)\cdot P(F2) + P(C|F3)\cdot P(F3)} \\
&= \frac{0.2\cdot \frac{6}{20}}{0.2\cdot \frac{6}{20} + 0.25 \cdot\frac{9}{20} + 0.1 \cdot \frac{5}{20}} \\
&\approx 0.3038
\end{align}

Your mistake is in choosing 0.6, 0.5, etc. F1 has 6 ferries out of 20, so $P(F1) = \frac{6}{20}$ and so on...

Comment: Are you using P(C) as the total probability of the ferry being delayed? What I think you're doing is calculating the probability of F1 being late and dividing that by the total probability of all ferrys being late. Would that be right?

Comment: Yes, C denotes the person being delayed, which is the disjoint union of person being delayed on each of the ferries.

Comment: Yes, that is so.  Thus giving the probability for the ferry being from company one given that it is delayed.

Comment: @AbhiramNatarajan Many thanks, I understand it now.